# jQuery/Json - Cannot convert 'data' to object

Tags: jquery, json

I've a simple ajax/json request with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/some-json-url",
              data: "score=" + 1,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data){
                if(data.msg){ 
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
             }
        });
```

However, if the msg is not set, I gen an error (looking through Opera Dragonfly):

**Unhandled Error: Cannot convert 'data' to object**

How can I check if it exists or not... in a valid way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem is with `data` being null then you can check it like so:

```
if(data && data.msg){
    //...
}
```

or if you have multiple properties, either like this:

```
if(data){
    if(data.msg){
        //...
    }
}
```

or return early:

```
if(!data)
    return;

if(data.msg){
    //...
}
```

Comment: That was the problem... being empty! Thx alot!